# When uploading files in Chrome, how do I choose the file browser?

Tags: nautilus, google-chrome, filemanager, default, dolphin

When trying to upload a file/image in Chrome you get the default file browser. I think it's Thunar or Nautilus. I changed my default file browser to Dolphin file explorer however.

All my folders and stuff open in Dolphin, but when I upload an image using Chrome, the file picker opens Nautilus. Does someone know how I can change this to use Dolphin instead?

I want to change it because Nautilus doesn't show previews when you pick an image.

Comment: Disclaimer : I haven't did it myself. You need to change the default file manager to Dolphin. Please refer to this link(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager) - it talks about changing the default file manager to Thunar but it should be applicable in your case also.

Comment: Doubt that's possible , because apps typically have hard coded file selection dialog. It's just because Nautilus and Chrome use gtk as their graphics platform, so they look rather similar

Comment: I'm having a simmilar problem, but it seems unsolvable: https://superuser.com/questions/944119/replace-gtk-file-dialog-with-alternative